# Intentionally using old company address

Tags: payment, invoice

My company moved to a new address.  I notified all my clients.  One client continues to pay invoices at the old address despite many many requests to update the address.  It has been over 6 months now.  Eventually, I expect that USPS will no longer forward mail from my old address to the new one.

At what point can my client be held liable for sending payments to the wrong address?  It appears to be intentional since requests to update the address are systematically ignored, causing delays in payments.

Comment: What do you mean by "held liable" here?  What law do you think they may be breaking?  If you no longer receive their payments then you have the usual recourse for any unpaid accounts.  As a practical matter, have you simply tried calling and talking to your contact(s) at this company personally?

Comment: @jwh20 I think the OP is worried if that they take action against the client for unpaid invoices, that the client will turn around and say "We did pay it, not our problem"

Comment: I get that, but a mailed check to the wrong address is unlikely to be viewed as "paid" in most cases.

Comment: I worked for a company whose payments sometimes didn't arrive, and the reason was the (one) person in their accounts department was writing cheques to her son. When found out she was jailed for fraud. So watch out that this isn't a set-up for a similar scam. Contact someone in their company who does not work in the accounts department.

Comment: @WeatherVane It's also worth noting that payment info and address changes can be a scam too. A fraudster sends a fake e-mail or fax asking address, payee information, or bank account numbers to be changed to something they control.

Comment: @user71659 in UK now when changing address, the company will mail the confirmation to the old address.

Comment: @jwh20, I don't have anything in mind regarding "held liable", but that's what I'm hoping the SE community can help with.  I have talked to this client by phone and they have said they'd take care of it, but nothing gets done.  Is that due to negligence, laziness, or something else?  I don't know.  What I do know is they used to pay invoices by electronic transfer, then transitioned to paper checks.  I'd like to 'motivate' them using contractual or legal recourse.

Comment: As long as you continue accepting payments at the old address, I doubt there is anything more you can do.  Once you stop receiving these forwarded by the postal service then you will have unpaid invoices which you can start the collections process.  Hopefully that will be enough to get them to change.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm afraid of.  The lack of payments is a hassle that I'd like to head off.

Answer (score -1):

### If they don’t pay you, you can sue them

They haven’t paid you by sending a check to an incorrect address.

Comment: I think it's more complicated than that. A contract often has a procedure to give notice, so the OP would have to ensure that is followed with sufficient evidence. For example, they may have to send a letter detailing the change certified mail return receipt requested to a particular address.

Comment: @user71659, I'll have to go back to the contract to see if certified mail is required.  I have notified them by email and by phone already.